# DiagrammeR grViz labelfontsize and labelfontcolor do nothing

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

I want to change the color and size of the text above the edges of a graph.
According to the docs, `labelfontsize` and `labelfontcolor` should do it for `taillabel` and `headlabel` (and indeed they do).

**How do I do it if I want to place my label on the center of the edge using `label`?**

Here's an example of "something red" showing in black and `fontsize=20`. If you change `label` for `headlabel`, arguments work as expected.

```
DiagrammeR::grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {
  
  # a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 20, rankdir='LR']

  # several 'node' statements
  node [shape = circle,
        fixedsize = true,
        width=0.9,
        fontname = Helvetica]
  A; B
  A -> B [label='something red', labelfontsize=2, labelfontcolor=red]
  }
")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```r
DiagrammeR::grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {
  
  # a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 20, rankdir='LR']

  # several 'node' statements
  node [shape = circle,
        fixedsize = true,
        width=0.9,
        fontname = Helvetica]
  A; B
  A -> B [label='something red', fontsize=15, fontcolor='#ff0000']
  }
")
```

[image: red]

https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2015-03-28/web/packages/DiagrammeR/README.html

Comment: oh wow...I don't know why I couldn't find that...